# jenkins execute protractor with robojs can't handle mouse

Tags: jenkins, protractor

I'm calling protractor from jenkins with pipeline

```
protractor conf.js --suite SetUpTPs
```

in the code I have call to get mouse location

```
browser.sleep(1000).then(() => {
    var robot = require("robotjs");
    robot.setMouseDelay(1000);
    var mouse = robot.getMousePos();
    var screenSize = robot.getScreenSize();
    console.log("getMousePos " + mouse.x + " " + mouse.y);
    robot.moveMouseSmooth(FromXCordinate, FromYCordinate);
    robot.mouseClick("left");
    mouse = robot.getMousePos();
    console.log("getMousePos " + mouse.x + " " + mouse.y);
    robot.mouseToggle('down');
    robot.moveMouseSmooth(xStart, 235 + YCordinate);
    robot.mouseToggle("up");
    mouse = robot.getMousePos();
    console.log("getMousePos " + mouse.x + " " + mouse.y);
});
```

when I look on the log on jenkins I got

```
getMousePos -1173274063 32758
```

how to fix the mouse coordinates ?

Comment: Why are you using robotjs to simulate actions that protractor/webdriver can do?  seems like an unnecessary package

Comment: It’s on canvas, I don’t have html to capture